# react-router-dom switch not rendering components after dynamic path

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I`ve been following an e-commerce tutorial and building on top of it. Im new to React and React Router Dom.
I've set a dynamic path for individual product pages, and now i' trying to add some new paths i.e. contact, about, etc.. If I add the new paths above the dynamic path they are rendered properly, but if I place the routes under the one with the dynamic path, for example the /hello, they won't render. Is this normal behaviour??

```
<Router>
<div>
    <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Home products={products} handleAddToCart={handleAddToCart} fetchProduct={fetchProduct} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/checkout">
            <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} handleCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} refreshCart={refreshCart} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart
                cart={cart}
                handleUpdateCartQuantity={handleUpdateCartQuantity}
                handleRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart}
                handleEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart}
            />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/contact">
            <Contact />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/:id">
            <Details product={product} handleAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/hello">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</div>
<Router>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is ***completely*** normal, and expected. Recall that the [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component "Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location." This means that in the `Switch` component ***path order and specificity matter!***

A path `"/hello"` is ***more*** specific than `"/:id"`, so depending on route order may or may not be matched first. Or in other words, `"/hello"` can always be matched to `"/:id"`, but not always the other way around.

You should *always* order the routes from more specific paths to less specific paths, and if done correctly there should be a near **zero** need for the `exact` prop.

`"/hello"` is more specific than `"/:id"` which is more specific than `"/"`.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/checkout">
    <Checkout ... />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/cart">
    <Cart ... />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/contact">
    <Contact />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/hello">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/:id">
    <Details ... />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home ... />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

If you had a nested `"/contact/add"` route for example, this is ***more*** specific than `"/contact"` and should be listed *higher/before* in the `Switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the exact from the Route.

```
<Route exact path="/:id">
```

to:

```
<Route path="/:id">
```